# How does "cat << EOF" work in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, heredoc

I needed to write a script to enter multi-line input to a program (`psql`).

After a bit of googling, I found the following syntax works:

```
cat << EOF | psql ---params
BEGIN;

`pg_dump ----something`

update table .... statement ...;

END;
EOF
```

This correctly constructs the multi-line string (from `BEGIN;` to `END;`, inclusive) and pipes it as an input to `psql`.

But I have no idea how/why it works, can some one please explain?

I'm referring mainly to `cat << EOF`, I know `>` outputs to a file, `>>` appends to a file, `<` reads input from file.

What does `<<` exactly do?

And is there a man page for it?

Comment: That's probably a useless use of `cat`. Try `psql ... << EOF ...` 

See also "here strings". http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput?#Here_Strings

Comment: I'm surprised it works with cat but not with echo. cat should expect a file name as stdin, not a char string. psql << EOF sounds logical, but not othewise. Works with cat but not with echo. Strange behaviour. Any clue about that?

Comment: Answering to myself: cat without parameters executes and replicates to the output whatever send via input (stdin), hence using its output to fill the file via >. In fact a file name read as a parameter is not a stdin stream.

Comment: @Alex echo just prints it's command line arguments while `cat` reads stding(when piped to it) or reads a file that corresponds to it's command line args

Comment: @DennisWilliamson the link you posted has changed to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput?#Heredocs_And_Herestrings

Answer (score 732, accepted):

This is called ***heredoc*** format to provide a string into stdin. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells for more details.

---

From `man bash`:

> ### Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from
>   the current source until a line
>   containing only word (with no trailing
>   blanks)  is  seen.
>
> All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the
>   standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>           <<[-]word
>                   here-document
>           delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or
>   pathname expansion is performed on
>   **word**.  If any characters in **word** are
>   quoted, the
>   **delimiter** is the result of quote removal on **word**, and the lines
>   in the **here-document** are not expanded.
>   If **word** is unquoted, all lines of  the
>   **here-document**  are  subjected  to  parameter  expansion,  command
>   substitution, and arithmetic
>   expansion.  In the latter case, the
>   character sequence `\<newline>` is
>   ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.
>
> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab characters
>   are stripped from input lines and the
>   line containing **delimiter**.   This 
>   allows  here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

Comment: I was having the hardest time disabling variable/parameter expansion. All I needed to do was use "double-quotes" and that fixed it! Thanks for the info!

Comment: Concerning `<<-` please note that only leading *tab* characters are stripped -- not soft tab characters. This is one of those rare case when you actually need the tab character. If the rest of your document uses soft tabs, make sure to show invisible characters and (e.g.) copy and paste a tab character. If you do it right, your syntax highlighting should correctly catch the ending delimiter.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is more helpful than the ones below. It merely repeats information that can be found in other places (that have likely already been checked)

Comment: @BrDaHa, maybe it is not. Why the question? because of upvotes? it *was* the only one for several years. it's seen by comparing dates.

Comment: This excerpt from a man page has taught me how to write beautiful yet easy to understand docs. Amazing!

Comment: @Xeoncross, what do you mean use "double-quotes"?

Comment: Here is answered how to disable the expansion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839315/how-can-i-suppress-parameter-expansion-in-a-here-doc-in-bash

Answer (score 821):

The `cat <<EOF` syntax is very useful when working with multi-line text in Bash, eg. when assigning multi-line string to a shell variable, file or a pipe.

## Examples of `cat <<EOF` syntax usage in Bash:

### 1. Assign multi-line string to a shell variable

```sh
$ sql=$(cat <<EOF
SELECT foo, bar FROM db
WHERE foo='baz'
EOF
)
```

*The `$sql` variable now holds the new-line characters too. You can verify with `echo -e "$sql"`.*

### 2. Pass multi-line string to a file in Bash

```sh
$ cat <<EOF > print.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo \$PWD
echo $PWD
EOF
```

*The `print.sh` file now contains:*

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $PWD
echo /home/user
```

### 3. Pass multi-line string to a pipe in Bash

```sh
$ cat <<EOF | grep 'b' | tee b.txt
foo
bar
baz
EOF
```

*The `b.txt` file contains `bar` and `baz` lines. The same output is printed to `stdout`.*

Comment: 1. 1 and 3 can be done without cat; 2. Example 1 can be done with a simple multi-line string

Comment: Instead of creating another process with 'cat', why not use IFS='' read -r -d instead?

Comment: worth noting that when using `tee` instead of `cat`, `sudo` can be used to write to a file at a restricted location. Like e.g. `sudo tee /etc/somepath/file > /dev/null <<EOF ...`

Comment: I think `cat` is only for complete bash command with here-document, if without `cat` or other commands, the here-document started with symbol `<<` can not echo to the `stdout`, and the rest of the first line "grep 'b' | tee b.txt" could not get input.

Comment: Why does this answer have any upvotes at all? You just completely ignored the question, which was "how/why it works". Nobody asked for a list of random examples, and yet somehow it has more upvotes than the (correctly) accepted answer.

Comment: @EntangledLoops There was already an accepted answer when I added these extra examples. It turns out they were quite useful based on the number of upvotes. Peace.

Answer (score 505):

In your case, "EOF" is known as a "Here Tag". Basically `<<Here` tells the shell that you are going to enter a multiline string until the "tag" `Here`. You can name this tag as you want, it's often `EOF` or `STOP`.

Some rules about the Here tags:

1. The tag can be any string, uppercase or lowercase, though most people use uppercase by convention.
2. The tag will not be considered as a Here tag if there are other words in that line. In this case, it will merely be considered part of the string. The tag should be by itself on a separate line, to be considered a tag.
3. The tag should have no leading or trailing spaces in that line to be considered a tag. Otherwise it will be considered as part of the string.

example:

```
$ cat >> test <<HERE
> Hello world HERE <-- Not by itself on a separate line -> not considered end of string
> This is a test
>  HERE <-- Leading space, so not considered end of string
> and a new line
> HERE <-- Now we have the end of the string
```

Comment: this is the best actual answer ... you define both and clearly state the primary purpose of the use instead of related theory ... which is important but not necessary ... thanks - super helpful

Comment: @edelans you must add that when `<<-` is used leading tab will not prevent the tag from being recognized

Comment: your answer clicked me on "you are going to enter a multiline string"

Answer (score 149):

#### Quotes prevent parameter expansion

Without quotes:

```
a=0
cat <<EOF
$a
EOF
```

Output:

```
0
```

With quotes:

```
a=0
cat <<'EOF'
$a
EOF
```

or (ugly but valid):

```
a=0
cat <<E"O"F
$a
EOF
```

Outputs:

```
$a
```

#### Hyphen removes leading tabs

Without hyphen:

```
cat <<EOF
<tab>a
EOF
```

where `<tab>` is a literal tab, and can be inserted with `Ctrl + V <tab>`

Output:

```
<tab>a
```

With hyphen:

```
cat <<-EOF
<tab>a
<tab>EOF
```

Output:

```
a
```

This exists of course so that you can indent your `cat` like the surrounding code, which is easier to read and maintain. E.g.:

```
if true; then
    cat <<-EOF
    a
    EOF
fi
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for space characters: POSIX favored `tab` indentation here. Yikes.

#### POSIX 7

kennytm quoted `man bash`, but most of that is also POSIX 7: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04 :

> The redirection operators "<<" and "<<-" both allow redirection of lines contained in a shell input file, known as a "here-document", to the input of a command.
>
> The here-document shall be treated as a single word that begins after the next `<newline>` and continues until there is a line containing only the delimiter and a `<newline>`, with no `<blank>` characters in between. Then the next here-document starts, if there is one. The format is as follows:
>
> ```
> [n]<<word
>     here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> where the optional n represents the file descriptor number. If the number is omitted, the here-document refers to standard input (file descriptor 0).
>
> If any character in word is quoted, the delimiter shall be formed by performing quote removal on word, and the here-document lines shall not be expanded. Otherwise, the delimiter shall be the word itself.
>
> If no characters in word are quoted, all lines of the here-document shall be expanded for parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. In this case, the `<backslash>` in the input behaves as the `<backslash>` inside double-quotes (see Double-Quotes). However, the double-quote character ( '"' ) shall not be treated specially within a here-document, except when the double-quote appears within "$()", "``", or "${}".
>
> If the redirection symbol is "<<-", all leading `<tab>` characters shall be stripped from input lines and the line containing the trailing delimiter. If more than one "<<" or "<<-" operator is specified on a line, the here-document associated with the first operator shall be supplied first by the application and shall be read first by the shell.
>
> When a here-document is read from a terminal device and the shell is interactive, it shall write the contents of the variable PS2, processed as described in Shell Variables, to standard error before reading each line of input until the delimiter has been recognized.

Comment: In your last example discussing `<<-` and `<tab>a`, it should be noted that the purpose was to allow normal indentation of code within the script while allowing heredoc text presented to the receiving process to begin in column 0. It is a not too commonly seen feature and a bit more context may prevent a good deal of head-scratching...

Comment: How should i escape expension if some of the content in between my EOF tags needs to be expanded and some don't?

Comment: ...just use the backslash in front of the `$`

Comment: @JeanmichelCote I don't see a better option :-) With regular strings you can also consider mixing up quotes like `"$a"'$b'"$c"`, but there is no analogue here AFAIK.

Comment: I have used <<- in my script but it does not ignores the leading tab characters.

Comment: More on this, which character(s) needs to be escaped with this? (of course as you said the dollar sign `$`, but what else)

Comment: @jimmymcheung without quotes I think it is just like inside double quote `""` strings except that `"` double quotes themselves don't need to be escaped, as more or less addressed on the "If no characters in word are quoted" paragraph.

Comment: You can also prevent parameter expansion with a backslash: `cat <<\EOF`. I personally find this cleaner and with a more obvious intent, as it's inline with the general convention of using backslashes to escape things.

Answer (score 36):

**Using tee instead of cat**

Not exactly as an answer to the original question, but I wanted to share this anyway: I had the need to create a config file in a directory that required root rights.

The following does not work for that case:

```
$ sudo cat <<EOF >/etc/somedir/foo.conf
# my config file
foo=bar
EOF
```

because the redirection is handled outside of the sudo context.

I ended up using this instead:

```
$ sudo tee <<EOF /etc/somedir/foo.conf >/dev/null
# my config file
foo=bar
EOF
```

Comment: in your case use

sudo bash -c 'cat <<EOF >/etc/somedir/foo.conf
# my config file
foo=bar
EOF'

Comment: @likewhoa how about POSIX shell? any convention of `sudo bash -c`?

Comment: Thanks! That solved my confusion! Just to point out that `tee -a file << EOF` will append the multiline text to the file and not adding `>/dev/null` will print out the multiline text to the console

Answer (score 36):

`<< EoF` basically means:

`<<` - "read the multi-line input that begins from the next line onward, and treat it as if it's code in a separate file"

`EoF` - "stop reading immediately after the word `EoF` is found in the multi-line input"

As other answers have explained, the multi-line input is called a [Here Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) (i.e. it's a document that's being provided 'inline' or 'on the spot').

A Here Document is often used to generate output to be passed to a subsequent process. For example `cat << EoF` can be used to generate a desired output, using a Here Document.

Here's an example of using a Here Document to  create a text document on the fly:

```
cat << EoF > ./my-document.txt
Hello world
Have a nice day
EoF
```

Answer (score 13):

A little extension to the above answers. The trailing `>` directs the input into the file, overwriting existing content. However, one particularly convenient use is the double arrow `>>` that appends, adding your new content to the end of the file, as in:

```
cat <<EOF >> /etc/fstab
data_server:/var/sharedServer/authority/cert /var/sharedFolder/sometin/authority/cert nfs
data_server:/var/sharedServer/cert   /var/sharedFolder/sometin/vsdc/cert nfs
EOF
```

This extends your `fstab` without you having to worry about accidentally modifying any of its contents.

Answer (score 11):

note to mention that cat << \EOT (see the backslash) will not expand any variables inside, while cat << EOT will do.

examples:

```
FOO="bar"

cat << \EOT > foobar.txt
echo "$FOO"
EOT
```

will output:
echo $FOO

while:

```
FOO="bar"

cat << EOT > foobar.txt
echo "$FOO"
EOT
```

will output:
echo "bar"

Answer (score 9):

Example to create a json file:

```sh
cat << EoF > ./allaccess.json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EoF
```

> As a result:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Long story short, `EOF` marker(but a different literal can be used as well) is a heredoc format that allows you to provide your input as multiline.
A lot of confusion comes from how `cat` actually works it seems.
You can use `cat` with `>>` or `>` as follows:

```
$ cat >> temp.txt
line 1
line 2
```

While `cat` can be used this way when writing manually into console, it's not convenient if I want to provide the input in a more declarative way so that it can be reused by tools and also to keep indentations, whitespaces, etc.
Heredoc allows to define your entire input as if you are not working with `stdin` but typing in a separate text editor. This is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) article means by:

> it is a section of a source code file that is treated as if it were a
> separate file.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily an answer to the original question, but a sharing of some results from my own testing. This:

```
<<test > print.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo \$PWD
echo $PWD
test
```

will produce the same file as:

```
cat <<test > print.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo \$PWD
echo $PWD
test
```

So, I don't see the point of using the cat command.

Comment: which shell? I tested with bash 4.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 as well as bash 3.2 on OSX. Both created an empty file when just using `<<test` without `cat <<test`.

Answer (score 1):

@kennytm is correct that this is known as a `heredoc` pattern ([link](https://joshuatz.com/posts/2023/shell-heredocs-productive-fun-bash-and-beyond/)).

There's no need for `cat` if you're writing to file. Use `tee` instead:

```bash
tee filename.txt <<EOF
line1
line2
line3
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that here docs work in bash loops too. 
This example shows how-to get the column list of table:

```
export postgres_db_name='my_db'
export table_name='my_table_name'

# start copy 
while read -r c; do test -z "$c" || echo $table_name.$c , ; done < <(cat << EOF | psql -t -q -d $postgres_db_name -v table_name="${table_name:-}"
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE 1=1
AND table_schema = 'public'
AND table_name   =:'table_name'  ;
EOF
)
# stop copy , now paste straight into the bash shell ...

output: 
my_table_name.guid ,
my_table_name.id ,
my_table_name.level ,
my_table_name.seq ,
```

or even without the new line

```
while read -r c; do test -z "$c" || echo $table_name.$c , | perl -ne 
's/\n//gm;print' ; done < <(cat << EOF | psql -t -q -d $postgres_db_name -v table_name="${table_name:-}"
 SELECT column_name
 FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE 1=1
 AND table_schema = 'public'
 AND table_name   =:'table_name'  ;
 EOF
 )

 # output: daily_issues.guid ,daily_issues.id ,daily_issues.level ,daily_issues.seq ,daily_issues.prio ,daily_issues.weight ,daily_issues.status ,daily_issues.category ,daily_issues.name ,daily_issues.description ,daily_issues.type ,daily_issues.owner
```