# Bash declaratively defining a list to loop on

Tags: bash, loops

In bash I frequently make scripts where I loop over a list of strings that I define.

e.g.

```
for a in 1 2 3 4; do echo $a; done
```

However I would like to define the list (before the loop to keep it clean) so that it contains spaces and with out a separate file:

e.g. (BUT THIS WILL NOT WORK)

```
read -r VAR <<HERE
list item 1
list item 2
list item 3
...
HERE

for a in $VAR; do echo $a; done
```

The expected output above (I would like):

```
list item 1
list item 2
list item 3
etc...
```

But you will get:

```
list
item
1
```

I could use arrays but I would have to index each element in the array (*EDIT read answers below as you can append to arrays.. I did not know you could*).

**How do others declaratively define lists in bash with out using separate files?**

*Sorry I forgot to mention I want to define the list at the **top of the file** before the for loop logic*

Comment: It would be more helpful if you also specified *how* what you tried didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays aren't so hard to use:

```
readarray <<HERE
this is my first line
this is my second line
this is my third line
HERE

# Pre bash-4, you would need to build the array more explicity
# Just like readarray defaults to MAPFILE, so read defaults to REPLY
# Tip o' the hat to Dennis Williamson for pointing out that arrays
# are easily appended to.
# while read ; do
#    MAPFILE+=("$REPLY")
# done

for a in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do
    echo "$a"
done
```

This has the added benefit of allowing each list item to contain spaces, should you have that need.

Comment: is `MAPFILE` correct? I'm just wondering that `readarray` is not referenced.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear. If you don't specify an array for `readarray`, `MAPFILE` is used by default. (`mapfile` is another name for the `readarray` command.)

Comment: I like @chepner's answer best as I want to define the list/array before the for loop. I don't mind that it requires a newer bash as its for my own uses.

Comment: I've updated to include a quick replacement for `readarray`, should you find yourself using an old bash (such as ships with Mac OS X).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "HERE Document" like this:

```
while read a ; do echo "Line: $a" ; done <<HERE
123 ab c
def aldkfgjlaskdjf lkajsdlfkjlasdjf
asl;kdfj ;laksjdf;lkj asd;lf sdpf -aa8
HERE
```

Comment: I'm familiar with this its just that I want to define my list prior to the for loop.

Comment: In contrast to the accepted answer, this approach works under Mac OS X as well!

Answer (score 3):

```
while read -r line
do
    var+=$line$'\n'
done <<EOF
foo bar
baz qux
EOF

while read -r line
do
    echo "[$line]"
done <<<"$var"
```

Why would you need to index arrays? You can append to arrays and iterate over them without using indices.

```
array+=(value)
for item in "${array[@]}"
do
    something with "$item"
done
```

Comment: I did not know you could append to arrays thats why :)

Answer (score 2):

There are better answers here, but you can also delimit the read on `\n` and temporarily change the variable to split on newlines instead of whitespace in the `for` loop using the `IFS` environment variable.

```
read -d \n -r VAR <<HERE
list item 1
list item 2
list item 3
HERE

IFS_BAK=$IFS
IFS="\n"
for a in $VAR; do echo $a; done
IFS=$IFS_BAK
```

Answer (score 0):

When it's fine for you to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, you can make use of the `while read` construct and a "here document":

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE; do
    echo "${LINE}"
done << EOF
list item 1
list item 2
list item 3
EOF
```

ref: [How does ` cat << EOF` work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash)