# How to accommodate for spaces in a bash array

Tags: bash, sh

I am looping though a directory for a certain command; however, I do not know how to accommodate for spaces

```
#!/bin/bash

image=(`ls *.bmp *.jpeg *.jpg | sort`)
data=(`ls *.dat | sort`)

for ((i=0; i < ${#image[@]}; i++))
do
  echo ${image[$i]} ${data[$i]}
done
```

I ran this script and it returned

```
OIS032_OS.bmp Disc
OIS034_OS.bmp Cube
OIS035_OD.bmp 200x200_9-30-2010_OD
OIS035_OS.bmp _ILM_RNFLOb.dat
OIS036_OD.bmp OIS007_Optic
OIS036_OS.bmp Disc
```

I wanted the program to return this line

```
OIS016_OD.bmp  OIS016_Optic Disc Cube 200x200_OS _ILM_RNFLOb.dat
```

How do I fix bash array to store what I need

```
data=(`ls *.dat | sort`)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't call `ls`; just use pattern matching to populate the array:

```
shopt -s extglob    # We'll use a more complicated glob to avoid needing to sort
image=( *.@(bmp|jpeg|jpg) )
data=( *.dat )

for ((i=0; i < ${#image[@]}; i++))
do
  echo ${image[$i]} ${data[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I feeling little off today-added this line because stack overflow mininum character comment

Comment: Without requiring extglob, you can use [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion): `image=( *.{bmp,jpeg,jpg} )`

Comment: Compare `a=(*.{bmp,jpeg,jpg})` and `b=(*.@(bmp|jpeg|jpg))` for the three files `a.bmp`, `a.jpeg`, and `z.jpeg`. I used the extended pattern to mimic the sorting shown in the original question, while the brace expansion would result in 3 separate patterns that would undergo filename expansion separately.

Comment: Thank you guys. I for explaining the complexities of bash. I will always use it to help write my scripts. I am wondering why I am saying thank you twice

Answer (score 1):

I believe but am not certain you can do what you want with `readarray` and `MAPFILE`.

I asked something similar like this: [Bash declaratively defining a list to loop on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687313/bash-declaratively-defining-a-list-to-loop-on)

Here another similar answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220619/318174