# How can I suppress parameter expansion in a here-doc in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'd like to do the following in bash, but without having variables interpolated:

```
cat >aBashScript.sh <<EOL
$name
EOL
```

The file should contain `$name`, but instead it's empty.  How does one do that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can disable parameter expansion in [here documents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html#EX71C) by quoting the limit string:

```
cat >aBashScript.sh <<'EOL'
$name
EOL
```

Comment: Yep, perfect! see example 19-7 for more details.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the dollar sign, simply prefix it with a backslash to escape it like so:

```
cat >aBashScript.sh <<EOL
\$name
EOL
```

Or disable quoting as @Michael suggested.