# Linux bash - dynamic config file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I try to combine two bash files to create a dynamic configuration file. One of these files (settings.sh) contains variables and the other (config.sh) commands to execute on them.

For instance, in settings.sh I have

```
DATABASE='name_of_the_db'
USER='name_of_the_user'
```

and config.sh contains

```
. settings.sh
[...]
'NAME': '$DATABASE',
'USER': '$USER',
[...]
```

I'm struggling to create a command that would get the variable in the first file and insert it in the second, rendering a new file (settings.py) containing

```
'NAME': 'name_of_the_db',
'USER': 'name_of_the_user',
```

I tried a command like

cat < settings.py
[...]
EOF

as proposed here [How does ` cat << EOF` work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash) but this does obviously not perform any variable replacement.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to use double quotes " instead of single onnes ' in lines:[...]
'NAME': '$DATABASE',
'USER': '$USER',
[...]

Comment: Thanks Roman, double quotes were missing indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do :

`settings.sh` is OK

`config.sh` :

```
. settings.sh
cat<<EOF
[...]
'NAME': "$DATABASE",
'USER': "$USER",
[...]
EOF
```

And to create the `config.py` file :

```
chmod +x config.sh
./config.sh > config.py
```

The double quotes in `config.sh` are **mandatory**, if you want the variables to be interpolated. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting