# Bash double redirection (<<==) meaning?

Tags: bash

What does the <<== in redirection mean?

```
sftp blah@server <<== >> test.log
```

What is the user trying to input to the command?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [here document/heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). From the [bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only word (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> <<[-]word
>     here-document
> delimiter
> ```

Example:

```
$ cat <<==
> Hello
> World
> ==
```

Gives:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Additionally an extract from the corresponding manpage.

`This  type  of  redirection  instructs the shell to read input from the
       current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing
       blanks)  is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used
       as the standard input for a command.

       The format of here-documents is:

              <<[-]word
                      here-document
              delimiter`