# provide interactive parameters for

Tags: shell, cat

I have a shell command "/var/tmp/shcommand" which interactively accepts 3 parameters(press enter after each parameter).Will the following commands work?

```
cat <<EOF |
    param1
    param2
    param3
EOF
/var/tmp/shcommand
```

Comment: yes it is working , why you are doing it complex way? Please refer the below link [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash

Comment: because i dont have permission to change /var/tmp/shcommand but just call it. Is there another way to make the calling simpler?

Comment: you can create a parmfile which contains param1, param2,param3 in 3 lines and call the script like /var/tmp/shcommand < parmfile  You can change he parmfile whenever you want.