# Postgres: Pipeline to psql

Tags: linux, postgresql, pipe

I have a simple question, but I can't find an answer )

I have following script:

```
sqsh -S SyBaseServer -U sybuser -P mypass -C 'select top 10000 * from dba.sybtable; -mbcp' | \
awk '{print substr($0, 0, length($0)-1)}' | \
psql -1 postgresql://admin:adminpass@pgserv:5432/pgbase -f sybtopg.sql
```

How can I add EOF after last string of ouput of awk? I must close STDIN for psql.

Thanks!

PS
The reason of fail isn't lack of EOF.
It's right pipeline:

```
sqsh -S SyBaseServer -U sybuser -P mypass -C 'select top 10000 * from dba.wybtable; -mbcp' \
| awk '{print substr($0, 0, length($0)-1)}' | \
/psql  postgresql://admin:adminpass@pgserv:5432/pgbase -c "DELETE FROM testtable; COPY testtable FROM STDIN DELIMITER '|' CSV"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does \` cat << EOF\` work in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash)

Comment: `awk` will write EOF when it reads EOF from its input.

Comment: @t0mm13b How is this related? There's no here-doc in this question.

Comment: IIUC the reader of a pipe should receive EOF when the (last) writing descriptor is closed, i.e. here when awk ends. Does awk linger for some reason (e.g. because sqsh does not finish and awk's input is still open)? Check with ps from another terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. When `awk` reaches EOF on its input, it will execute its `END` block (if there is one) and then exit, and this will close the pipe. That will then cause the next process in the pipeline to read EOF.

If you want the `awk` script to send EOF earlier than that, it will have to exit, by using the [`exit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) statement.

Comment: Yes, You're right. The reason of fail isn't lack of EOF. Thanks!