# run multiple zkCli commands

Tags: bash, apache-zookeeper

I want to run two commands together for zkCli.

```
zkCli addauth digest username:password && zkCli setAcl /zknode-path world:anyone:crdwa
```

I have already set the ACL value for a zknode, and want to revert it back. But running this command give, authentication is not valid. How to run these two commands in one session?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run multiple commands in zkCli using ***heredoc*** format
(see [How does ` cat << EOF` work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash))

Insert this snippet into a bash file

```
TMPVAR="addauth digest username:password\nsetAcl /zknode-path world:anyone:crdwa"

/zookeeper-3.4.10/bin/zkCli.sh <<EOF
$(echo -e ${TMPVAR})
quit
EOF
```

First, we set *TMPVAR* with both commands you wanted to execute in a single zkCli session, with a \n delimiter between them

Then we evaluate *TMPVAR* into STDIN line by line and this will make zkCli execute command after command, and then finally execute *quit*