# What does <<$$$ mean in a Unix shell?

Tags: linux, shell, curl, google-http-client

I'm using the `google-http-client` for a project at work and when I do some requests I have the following thing printed on my console.

```
curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.23.0 (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'http://example.com' << $$$
```

I was wondering what `<< $$$` mean.

If I try to run this command into a linux terminal seems that `<< $$$` makes the console to wait for more input. If that's the case, how can I specify to the terminal that I'm done feeding inputs to it?

Later edit: I have found that curl arguments `-d @-` implies that data will be red from the stdin.

Comment: It is a heredoc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500451/9305398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "here-document" with an unusual end marker.

A here-document is a type of redirection, and usually looks like

```
utility <<MARKER
document
content
goes here
MARKER
```

That is, it feeds a document delimited by `MARKER` to the utility on its standard input.

This is *like* `utility <file` where `file` contains the lines in the here-document, except that the shell will do variable expansion and command substitution on the text of the document (this may be prevented by quoting the marker as either `\MARKER` or `'MARKER'` at the start).

The here-document marker can be any word, but `$$$` is a highly unusual choice of word for it.  As `$` has a special meaning in the shell, using `$` in the marker is, or may be, confusing to the reader.

If you type

```
somecommand <<stuff
```

in the shell, the shell expects you to give the rest of the contents of the here-document, and then the word `stuff` on a line by itself.  That's how you signal end of input in a here-document.

Comment: `$$$` is not a "bad" heredoc marker since shell will not expand it.  It is definitely not an ideal choice since it can confuse the reader.  Nicely explained here: [How does “cat << EOF” work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500451/6862601).

Comment: @codeforester That's what I meant. Since `$` has a special meaning in the shell, seeing `$$$` as an unquoted string is highly unusual. I will reword it.