# Cannot create a file remotely via SSH using cat and <<EOF

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to create a file remotely via ssh with the command as follows:

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST "
    cat > hooks/post-receive <<EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    git checkout -f
    EOF
    chmod +x hooks/post-receive
"
```

After it is successfully executed when I check the file with `cat repo.git/hooks/post-receive` on remote server I see the following result:

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout -f
EOF
chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

I expect `EOF` and `chmod +x hooks/post-receive` not to be present in `post-receive` file.
What can be done to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "cat << EOF" work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> **Here Documents**
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source **until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing blanks)** is seen.
>
> ...
>
> If  the  redirection  operator  is  <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.  This allows  here-documents  within  shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

So, you need to remove trailing spaces from your here document or substitute them with tabs.

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST "
cat > hooks/post-receive <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
git checkout -f
EOF
chmod +x hooks/post-receive"

# or,

ssh $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST "
cat > hooks/post-receive <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    git checkout -f
    EOF
    chmod +x hooks/post-receive"
```

Comment: or use `<<-` and then everything must be indented with a **tab** and the tab will be ignored in the output.

Comment: Concerning <<- please note that only leading tab characters are stripped -- not soft tab characters.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks, edited to add info about <<-.

Comment: Good deal, that rounds out the completeness of the answer.