# Create Secret in ConfigMap using Shell Script

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I'm trying to create a secret from ConfigMap using the below commands:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-single-ca-script
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "couchbase-cluster.name" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "couchbase-cluster.chart" . }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
data:
  single-ca-script.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    kubectl create secret generic {{ include "couchbase-cluster.pki.secret.tls" . }}-trf \
      --from-file=chain.pem=/var/run/certs/tls.crt --from-file=pkey.key=/var/run/certs/tls.key
    WORKDIR=/tmp/
    cd $WORKDIR
    csplit -f ca_- /var/run/certs/ca.crt '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/' '{*}'
    for x in `ls $WORKDIR/ca_*`; do
     echo "checking ca: $x"
     openssl verify -verbose -CAfile $x /var/run/certs/tls.crt
     if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      CORRECT_CA_FILE=$x
      break;
     fi
    done
    if [[ -z $CORRECT_CA_FILE ]]; then
     echo "NO correct CA file found"
     exit 99
    fi
    mv $CORRECT_CA_FILE $WORKDIR/ca.crt
    kubectl create secret generic {{ include "couchbase-cluster.pki.secret.tls" . }}-single-ca \
     --from-file=$WORKDIR/ca.crt

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -\
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "couchbase-cluster.fullname" . }}
  labels:
  app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "couchbase-cluster.name" . }}
  app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
  helm.sh/chart: {{ include "couchbase-cluster.chart" . }}
```

But I'm facing the error

> Error: YAML parse error on
> platform-couchbase-cluster/templates/configMap-single-ca.yaml: error
> converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 39: could not find expected ':'

Could you please let me know if I'm missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Please update your question to support the point that is mentioned under Max Lobur answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. `cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -\` Looks unneeded
2. Secret indentation after `labels:` is broken

Comment: Fixed point 2 .. still same error.
For point1 - I am tying to create the secret inside shell script

Comment: then you are missing EOF in the end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549836/923620