# how to wrap huge one line string with external variables solving to document file

Tags: bash

I mean something like this

```
<{ any text; "with double quotes"; some $VARIABLE here; and 'single quotes'; and semicolons; } >| doc.txt
```

we have several quotes types and many nested variables to be solved.

we dont want to escape symbols.

with here-documents, you must have two lines.

with here-string, you must escape all nested quotes.

any logical solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does "cat << EOF" work in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500436/how-does-cat-eof-work-in-bash)

Comment: my man. you go to 2 lines ...

Comment: Then you want a here-string: `cat > doc.txt <<< "your big string here"` -- you will have to escape any double quotes in the string, no avoiding that (except with a here-**doc** that you don't want)

Comment: we have nested quotes ...

Comment: Why exactly do you want a oneliner ? There's no need for that if you use your command in a script. Are you using this in an interactive shell ?

Comment: one liner aproche is better script performance :):)

Comment: I do not believe there is any evidence that multiline script has lower performance than single line. Rather the opposite, because of tokenization I would expect multiline scripts to perform indistinguishably better. `any logical solution ?` I do not understand, the logical solution is to use multiline lines and a here document, which is readable and maintainable in the long run. `we dont want to escape symbols.` Yet, you want `$VARIABLE` to expand. It is not possible - if you want `$VARIABLE` to expand, you have to have escape symbols for the case if you want `$VARIABLE` string preserved.

Comment: Writting an instruction on 1 line or 2 does **not** change performance in any way. If you have a complex one-liner, you are better off splitting the instructions for better readability/maintainability

Answer (score 1):

If the currently executed script is an actually existing file, you can get the current line and extract from it the text that you want to preserve, whereas the text may be stored as a comment after a special delimiter. With `envsubst` you can substitute variable expansions of exported variables. Something along:

```
sed -n "${BASH_LINENO}s/.*### //p" "$0" | VARIABLE="$VARIABLE" envsubst '$VARIABLE' > doc.txt  ### any text; "with double quotes"; some $VARIABLE here; and 'single quotes'; and semicolons;
```

You could also, in the same fashion, create an `eval` that would use that line content inside an `eval`-ed single line generated here-document:

```
eval "cat <<EOF$(echo)$(sed -n "${BASH_LINENO}s/.*### //p" "$0")$(echo EOF)" > doc.txt   ### any text; "with double quotes"; some $VARIABLE here; and 'single quotes'; and semicolons;
```

---

With `base64 -w0` (or many other encoding) you can encode any script, also multiline, into a single line. Remove `echo` from below to actually execute the script.

```
echo eval "$(base64 -d <<<Y2F0IDw8RU9GCmFueSB0ZXh0OyAid2l0aCBkb3VibGUgcXVvdGVzIjsgc29tZSAkVkFSSUFCTEUgaGVyZTsgYW5kICdzaW5nbGUgcXVvdGVzJzsgYW5kIHNlbWljb2xvbnM7CkVPRgo=)" > doc.txt
```